# Accidentally deleted /lib directory

Tags: 14.04

> I accidentally deleted `/lib` directory on my Ubuntu box.

How do I recover it?

Answer (score 1):

Everything on the drive (except everything under /home, which holds user accounts and their data) can be restored by simply taking a live DVD/CD sidk and doing the install process again.  But there is a catch:
You must select the LAST option in the list of how to install it, and make choices that reflect where you want root (/) that reflects your current install, use the same format option (typically ext4), and **make sure you do NOT click on the format box**.  If you format, you will lose the`.home directory` and user accounts.  You will see a warning about not reformating, but you can safely ignore that and continue on.

You will lose all your software updates, but you can get most of those back with a few commands in the terminal window:  I will show you here a simplified string of the two you need most:
`sudo apt-get -qq update`
`sudo apt-get -qq -y update`

The `-qq` limits the amount of messaging that appears on the screen during these processes.  Leave it out if you want to see everything.  The `-y`tells `apt-get` to just do it, and it does not stop to ask you (Yn).

Some software does not get handled this way.  You have to deal with each one separately.  For instance, Virtualbox, Chrome, Chromium, Slimjet, and some other add-on software need to be reinstalled.

Another possibility is to install the same version of Linux on a different drive, then copy the `/lib` folder and contents over to your present drive.  You could use a USB thumbnail drive for this.  Ubuntu warns you that you need at least 6.5GB for an install though, and it may effect what you already have on the USB drive.  For that method to work, you have to have both drives mounted, and use the `/media/ubuntu/` folder setup to access the drive(s).

I say drives in plural, because you can do this from the LiveCD in Try mode, open a terminal, and type in `sudo -su` or `sudo -i`.  From the LiveCD, there is no password required to become super user.  Then you can use the mount command to mount each drive.  I won't explain the mount command here, but it isn't that hard, and you can find details elsewhere.

With both drives mounted. you use the `cp -r` command to copy from a source to a destination.  Unlike Windows, you cannot specify a current directory or folder on two separate devices.  Your current directory is limited to one place, which by default. is your `/home/userid/`.  You can use the cd command to change your current directory of you want, so lets assume you want to copy the `/lib` from sdb2 to sda1.  You could befin this way:
`sudo -i`
`cd /media/ubuntu/sdb2`     'assuming the drive is mounted already
`dir /media/ubuntu/sda1/lib`   'see if the target directory alreasy exist,   which likely it doesn't
`mkdir /media/ubuntu/sda1/lib`  'again, assuming sda1 has been mounted first
`cp -rpf . /media/ubuntu/lib/`  'the period means from the current directory and the -rpf means -r to reiterate through subfolders, the p means don't change permissions, and the f means force an overwrite if it already exists.

You could do it a bit simpler if you did it this way:
`cd /media/ubuntu/sdb1`
`cp -rpf ./lib /media/ubuntu/sda1/`

The options `pf -p`  and `-f` may be overkill here, but they are quite handy under other circumstances of using the cp command, which of course stands for "copy".

Note the use of the period again.  Without it, you would be copying the contents of the/lib on the root drive over -- which might work.  But if doing this from the LiveCD, the contents of /lib are likely curtailed from having everything a full install of Ubuntu would have.

The marvel of Linux is that /home need not be on the same drive or partition with root (/).  You could do a second drive/partition install, and during the install process, set it up to see /home on the original drive while seeing everything else on the new install drive.

In fact, the purpose of several drives and partitions can be managed this way. You just need to pick "Something else" as your install choice, then manage the configuration yourself.  This also lets you delete partitions, create new partition, change the format of partitions, and resize partitions.

But there are a few issues involved.  Linux identifies partitions on any one drive in the order they are created.  You can start with three partition on the sda drive, and they could be sda1, sda2, and swap.  Then you decide to downsiae sda1 and sda2 and add a third partition which should be sda3. It gets done, but because of the sequence order you followed in doing this, you end up with sda1, sda3, sda2, swap. You delete sda3, try to move sda2 down, and try to recreate sda3 where sda2 was.  Now you end up with sda1, sda2, sda3, swap.  The label sda3 is already taken, even though you deleted the partition.  So it is best to plan all this out ahead of time, then work down the list, from the first one to the last.  The swap partition can go anywhere.  I always put it last but others put it first.  Its generally sized at 1.5 time the a,ount od RAM you have, though I don't know why.  With less RAM, you would think you need more swap space, and the opposite with more RAM. since there is less need to swap.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You had to do this as root so I don't think easy 'recovering' is possible.

First thing You could try is using some data recovering tool such as TestDisk.

Another option is just coping it from USB drive or CD after launching Ubuntu live session from it. Honestly that's only my guess, it may not work.

The last solution I can think of is reinstalling You system - You can do this saving Your data and some applications, not necessary loosing everything.